# How do I extend PointNormal class with my own parameter?

Tags: c++, class, oop, point-cloud-library

I am developing a robotic navigation system using PCL. I don't have much experience with C++, so my question may look stupid. I want to add one (or few) parameters to PointNormal class. As I understand OOP, I should make a subclass from PointNormal, but I have also few functions, which I want to use, that return PointNormal objects. I found out, that it's impossible, to cast superclass into a subclass, though I don't understand, what do I do in my specific case.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you're using a strange solution to a problem that has a standard one.

Comment: What is the standard solution?

Comment: What do you want to do? Why do you need to add parameters? You aren't adding parameters for the sake of having them, are you? My point is: trying to add parameters to a class using inheritance looks like a wrong solution to  some other problem.

Comment: @kraskevich I need to mark points as obstacles. There is also a way to delete them but i have a structured point cloud (640x480) and I don't want it to be shifted.

Comment: I still don't fully get the question, but it seems to me that you can either: create a `bool` array of an appropriate size to store flags or create a new class that has a point and a bool flag.

Comment: @kraskevich well, I can use a bool array, but an extended class seems to be more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the way PCL writers intended you to do this was through creating your own custom PointT type.  http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php